# How to fix AVFoundation bridge support at runitime with system python/pyobjc on Mac OS X 10.15?

Tags: python, macos-catalina, pyobjc

When importing AVFoundation with the system provided python (2.7.16) and pyobjc (2.5.1) on Mac OS X 10.15, there is an error:

```
% python
Python 2.7.16 (default, Feb 29 2020, 01:55:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.29.20) (-macos10.15-objc- on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import objc
>>> objc.__version__
'2.5.1'
>>> import AVFoundation
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/objc/_bridgesupport.py:674: RuntimeWarning: Error parsing BridgeSupport data for AVFoundation: PyObjCRT_SkipTypeSpec: Unhandled type '5d' ]}
  warnings.warn("Error parsing BridgeSupport data for %s: %s" % (frameworkName, e), RuntimeWarning)
```

On consequence of that (as far as I understand), is that constants are not loaded.
Would it be possible to fix that from the running script?

I can not alter the python install because my script has to work on other machines than mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the answer your looking for, but the best solution is to install Python 3.8 and a recent version of PyObjC.

Both Python 2.7 and the version of PyObjC included in macOS are no longer supported.

Comment: yes, I will bite the bullet and vendor pyobjc with my application… thanks for the answer, and for pyobjc!